# How to embed draggable YouTube video (while playing)

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, draggable

- **Goal:** Make an embedded YouTube video draggable
- **Approach:** Using jQuery `.draggable()` doesn't work directly on the embedded iframe
- **Solution:** Adding a layer to be used to drag the video, thereby covering the video and removing the possibility to interact with the video
- **Question:** Is there another way to make it draggable (even while playing) and if not, is this a legit implementation? At least I did not found anything against it in the [YouTube terms](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service)

```js
$('#wrapper').draggable();
//$('iframe').draggable(); does not work
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <!--<div class="overlay"></div> this is needed unfortunately in order for draggable to work -->
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HgvIox6ehkM?controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar and used thumbnail youtube api + YT player. I put the thumbnail with a higher z-index (position:absolute) on the iframe that is below it. When I click the play button I hide the thumbnail (I used custom play button on thumbnail).

Comment: OK, thanks - so when you hit play, the overlay disappears and the movie is not draggable anymore, right? I need to drag the movie while it is playing...

Comment: Try with full transparency of the thumbnail (higher z-index, position: absolute). You will have to adjust the events (drag, click).
When you click, hide the thumbnail(play/stop video), and when you drag, stay over it. For sure, in my opinion, you will have to use the Yt player api to manage the functionality..

Comment: Actually, it is kind of tricky, since once you hide the overlay, how do you bring it back... I solved it by adding an additional button on the side to toggle the mode/layer